# Referencing DOM Elements with React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating references to DOM elements in order to use React Hooks for functional components like so:

```
        let link1, link2 = useRef();

        <ul>
            <li>
               <a ref={element => { link1 = element;}}>FAQ</a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a ref={element => { link2 = element;}}>Contact Us</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Question is, do I have to create references for every DOM element I want to target like the above? I feel the code will grow quick.

Here's the [codepen](https://codepen.io/ericnguyen23/pen/wvwGjVG) for complete code.

Comment: why do you need to create a ref for every components? what's your use case? how do you plan to use them?

Comment: I agree with Federkun, generally you don't need to use refs in react, why do you need to assign a ref to each item in the list?  I am getting a real [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem#answer-66378) problem feeling from this question.

Comment: Apologies @AaronRoss I've included reference to my codepen.

Comment: @Federkun I'm trying to animate each element. See updated issue for codepen link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could alternatively create one ref for the parent element of all the elements that are related and crawl the node from there.

If you change your schema to:

```
const ulRef = useRef(null);
<ul ref={ulRef}>
        <li>
           <a className="link">FAQ</a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a className="link">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

<strike>You can crawl the nodes like this:</strike>

```
ulRef.current.children().children('a')
```

Which should return a nodeList of all of your links. 
^This was using a jQuery syntax that is still stuck in my head from years back....

You can use this command to create an HTMLCollection of your li nodes: `ulRef.current.children`, then iterate over them for the values you are wanting.

I created a simplified example on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tempsandbox-okypp).

Comment: I get a "Uncaught TypeError" when console logging `ulRef.current.children().children('a')` . When I log `ulRef.current` I do see the ul returned. I've added the codpen reference in original post.

Comment: I updated my answer as I provided incorrect syntax.

Comment: `ulRef.current.children` selects all children of `ul` which are all the `li`. Is it possible to select all the `<a>` with the current reference ? I was thinking `ulRef.current.children.children` but that returns undefined.

Comment: Ya, you can do this by referencing `ulRef.current` like any other node in Javascript and do a query on it.  
  
`ulRef.current.querySelectorAll('a')`